# How can we make text selectable with swift? ( ReactNative View Module )

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Hi I'm trying to create a native view in swift to be used in React Native, and I want to create a selectable TextView.

I want to create something like the example below.

[image]

To do this, I first wrote the code below.

```swift
import UIKit

  class SelectableTextView: UIView {
    override init (frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      setupView()
    }
      
    private func setupView() {
      self.addSubview(textField)
    }
    
    let textField: UITextField = {
      let field = UITextField()
      field.isEnabled = false
      
      field.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
      return field
    }()
    
    @objc func setValue(_ val: NSString) {
      textField.text = val as String?
    }
  }
```

However, it doesn't respond to pressing the text. How can I make the text selectable when pressed?

I'm not familiar with swift, but I'm trying to create this out of necessity.